# AJAX is changing the content of file_get_contents

Tags: php, ajax, file-get-contents

I am using AJAX to load content into a placeholder, the PHP code uses file_get_contents to get the page I want, then gives it back to the AJAX response which puts it into my placeholder. The problem I am having is that the content that is being grabbed is actually being altered, like html tags are being put where they didn't exist.. Here is the code:

```
function getPreview() { 
    var indexe = ajax.length;
    ajax[indexe] = new sack();
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    ajax[indexe].setVar("prevsub", form.ebay_preview_submit.value);
    ajax[indexe].method = 'POST';
    ajax[indexe].requestFile = "../admin/model/catalog/getEbay.php";
    ajax[indexe].onCompletion = function(){ createPreview(indexe) };
    ajax[indexe].runAJAX();
}

function createPreview(indexe) {    
    var obj = document.getElementById('preview_ph');
    obj.innerHTML = ajax[indexe].response;
}
```

so everything gets put inside of this placeholder: 
    `<div id="preview_ph" ></div>`

Here is the PHP that does the grabbing:

```
if(isset($_POST['prevsub'])){
$template_viewer = http://localhost:8888/admin/view/template/ebay/template_viewer.php';
$file_got = file_get_contents($template_viewer); 
echo $file_got;
}
```

And here is a snippet of what It is supposed to be vs what it is adding in there...

Supposed to be:

```
Sign up for Newsletter</a> </div></td>
```

But instead it is altered:

```
Sign up for Newsletter</a></td></tr>
```

Another, supposed to be:

```
bidding! </span>
</div>
</td></tr>
```

But gets altered to:

```
bidding! </span>
</div>
</td></tbody>
```

**It alters the content 7 total times from the page its grabbing... Any explanation for this?**

The page, opens up in a browser perfectly, it is seriously getting altered by AJAX or file_get_contents in some way, and I am completely baffled...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't trust what the browser says. Get a packet sniffer if you have to.

Comment: OK, can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To me, this looks like the browser is sanitizing the HTML at the time of the `.innerHTML` operation. That is an act of self-defense, because the HTML you output is clearly not valid, is it?

The end result would look like

```
<div id="preview_ph" > 
 Sign up for Newsletter
  </a>          <--- broken 
   </div>       <--- broken
    </td>       <--- broken
 </div>
```

that code would break the DOM, so the browser has to try and fix it as best as it can.

Why are you outputting those closing tags through AJAX?

Comment: Actually, I was just providing a snippet on my post, so what you pointed out actually really has all the matching tags etc. The full output is fully valid xhtml, so it doesn't make sense that the browser would try to fix it, there is nothing to fix...

Comment: Here is a link to the: 
[Good one](http://www.noextratime.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/newhtml2.html)

And the: 
[Bad one](http://www.noextratime.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/newhtml3.html)

Thanks!

Comment: @Josh that is good to have, but I mean the Ajax snippet that gets transmitted? Output by a `alert(data)` for example?

Comment: @Pekka, Figured out the answer.. the file_get_contents "content" was <table>....... </table>, I wrapped that with <html><body> and </body></html> and now it works perfectly.... I think the browser was trying to parse the content and freaking out because it was coming from a page with no <html> and <body> tags so it messed it all up. Now, the same content gets inserted via the innerHTML and it automatically drops the html and body tags and doesnt put those in the preview div... Awesome!

Comment: @Josh glad to hear that something works, but I wouldn't be comfortable with the solution: You can't trust every browser to sanitize the input like that. I would recommend checking out why it happens in the first place - this is *not* the way a normal Ajax request for some HTML will behave.

Comment: How do I go about checking why this happens? Someone else mentioned a packet sniffer, is that what I need? Can YOU point me int the right direction? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Josh try `alert()` ing what you get from the AJAX call: That should give you the unadulterated HTML that comes from the script.